# how to create live search knockout with list of map markers?

Tags: google-maps, knockout.js, marker, livesearch

I am trying to create live search knockout with list of locations and map markers, but when I create the markers as a part of the ViewModel, the code doesn't work with markers, it works with title of locations only.

My question is:

How to match every location with its marker without using google map API inside the view model, I already created array of markers before, but as I say viewmodel can't handle it. Any suggestions?

Here is my code for markers:

```
for (var i=0; i<locations.length; i++)
{
  var position = locations[i].location;
  var title = locations[i].title;
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  map: map,
  icon: 'http://1.bp.blogspot.com/_GZzKwf6g1o8/S6xwK6CSghI/AAAAAAAAA98/_iA3r4Ehclk/s1600/marker-green.png',
  position: position,
  title: title,
  animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
  id: i
});
```

viewmodel:

```
    // using knockout to make a live search
 function ViewModel(){
  var self =this;
  this.filter = ko.observable();

  this.locations = ko.observableArray(locations);
  this.markers = ko.observableArray(markers);
  this.visibleLocations = ko.computed(function(){
       return this.locations().filter(function(location){
           if(!self.filter() || location.title.toLowerCase().indexOf(self.filter().toLowerCase()) !== -1)
             return location;
             location.marker.setMap(matches ? self.map : null);
             //this.location.marker.setVisible(true);
        //marker.setVisible(true);
       });
   },this);

}

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

the view :

```
  <label for="filter">Filter:</label>
<input id="filter" type="text" data-bind="textInput: filter"/>
        <ul data-bind="foreach: visibleLocations">
           <li class="markers_info"> <a href="#" data-bind="text: title"> </a></li>
        </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so you have `this.filter` as an observable. Good. This won't need `this.locations` or `this.markers`. Just add a `marker` member to `locations` set up with a marker for that location. Then subscribe to changes to `this.filter`:

```
self.visibleLocations = ko.observableArray();
self.filter.subscribe(function (filterValue) {
    locations.forEach(function (location) {
        var matches =
            !filterValue ||
            location.title.toLowerCase().indexOf(filterValue.toLowerCase()) !== -1;
        location.marker.setMap(matches ? self.map : null);
    });
    self.visibleLocations(locations.filter(function (location) {
        return location.marker.getMap() != null;
    }));
});
```